# Contract Method not returning value

Tags: contract-development, truffle

I have a contract :

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.2;

import "Owned.sol";
contract SGBFactory is Owned {

    event SGBUpdate(uint sbgID, bool isCreated, string message); // isCreated = true means created, else means deleted

    string public ownerType;

    struct SGB {
        uint id;
        string latitude;
        string longitude;
        uint minBal; // should be in Wei since Solidity doesn't support floating points as of now
        string ownerType;
        uint capacity; //should also be in grams due to the same reasons as above
        address owner;
        uint fixedUnitCostPerTransaction;
    }

    SGB[] public sgbCollection;

    function SGBCreator() {
        ownerType = "COMMUNITY";
    }

    function addSGB(
        string lat,
        string lon,
        uint minBalReq,
        uint maxCapacity,
        address ownerAccount,
        uint fixedCost
    ) onlyOwner {
        uint sgbID = sgbCollection.length++; //note the postfix operator here
        sgbCollection[sgbID] = SGB(sgbID, lat, lon, minBalReq, ownerType, maxCapacity, ownerAccount, fixedCost);
          // fire up an event here
        SGBUpdate(sgbID,true, "A new SGB is created!!");
    }

    function getSGB(uint sgbid) returns (uint sbgID, string lat, string lon, uint minBal,string ownerType) {
        return(
            sgbCollection[sgbid].id,
            sgbCollection[sgbid].latitude,
            sgbCollection[sgbid].longitude,
            sgbCollection[sgbid].minBal,
            sgbCollection[sgbid].ownerType
        );
    }

    // uint maxCapacity, address owner, uint fixedCost
    // sgbCollection[sgbid].capacity,sgbCollection[sgbid].owner,sgbCollection[sgbid].fixedUnitCostPerTransaction
}
```

It is deployed in my private Ethereum chain. I can call getSGB() method from Truffle console and it returns value successfully.

I used the following mechanism in Truffle console:

```
var contract = SGBFactory.deployed();
contract.getSGB.call(1, {from: "0x85ded4eae096d15de9bee720a6e91eb28603a7e6"}, function(err, res) {
    console.log(res);
});
```

But when I call the same method from JS file, the method returns nothing, nor there is an error message.

SGBWatcher.js

```
var accounts;
var coinbase_account;

function getSGBFromFactory() {
    var sgbAdderContract = SGBFactory.deployed();
    console.log(coinbase_account);
    sgbAdderContract.getSGB.call(0, {from: coinbase_account }, function(err, res) {
        if (err != null)
            console.log(err);
        else
            console.log(res);
    });
}

window.onload = function() {
    web3.eth.getAccounts(function(err, accs) {
        if (err != null) {
            alert("There was an error fetching your accounts.");
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }

       if (accs.length == 0) {
           alert("Couldn't get any accounts! Make sure your Ethereum client is configured correctly.");
           return;
       }

       accounts = accs;
       coinbase_account = accounts[0];
   });
}
```

What could be the issue here? (I already have two SGBs added in the contract, so the indexes 0 and 1 as parameter should be fine.)

Answer (score 1):

1. You send 0 as argument in

   `sgbAdderContract.getSGB.call(0,{from: coinbase_account },function(err,res){ if(err != null) console.log(err); else console.log(res); });`

   Does identifier exist?
2. Ensure you realy call getSGBFromFactory() from your JS code

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, I have already added two SGBs. It works fine when called from Truffle console, but when I try to call it from a js file in truffle, it doesnt return anything.

Comment: @freerunner I can not see where you call getSGBFromFactory in JS code

Comment: I am calling it from a button onclick event in a html file. It was just one button in the page so I didnt put it here. I tried to check whether or not the function getSGBFromFactory() is called or not by putting a console.log(sgbAdderContract). It provides the ABI in console and also a RPC call is made. Yet the promise is not returned.

Answer (score 1):

Not certain this is it, but possibly.

In Truffle 0.3.x you might consider changing the contract instantiation to a callback.

Instead of

```
var sgbAdderContract = SGBFactory.deployed(); console.log(coinbase_account)
```

Consider

```
var sgbAdderContact;
SGBFactory.deployed(function(instance) { 
  sgbAdderContract = instance; 
  console.log(sgbAdderContract); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Rob. I called console.log(sgbAdderContract) in the getSGBFromFactory() function. And it is displaying the ABI just fine. So probably it's not a problem of instantiation. Its working fine on Truffle console which is why I am puzzled.

Answer (score 1):

`sgbCollection(uint _idx);` already exists as the [getter function](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html) of `SGB[] public sgbCollection;`. It will return the `struct SGB` element values as an array in the order of the struct.  Your front end only needs to map those to something meaningful if required. So `getSGB` is not actually required. If however there is some need of the named return parameters, then you should modify the function as `constant` as there is no state changes and so no need to create a transaction.

`function getSGB(uint sgbid) constant returns (uint sbgID, string lat, string lon, uint minBal,string ownerType) {...}`

Your JS then simply becomes `sgbAdderContract.getSGB(0)` or using the accessor `sgbAdderContract.sgbCollection(0)`

Answer (score 1):

The solution was :

```
sgbAdderContract.getSGB.call(0,{from : coinbase_account}).**then**(function(result){
//do somethiing
}).catch(function(e){
// error
});
```